# Inverse of $4 \times 4 $ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Would you be so kind to provide me some examples of  $4 \times 4 $ matrices that satisfy the relation  $AB = I $

I am completely clueless to find randomly any two matrix $A$ & $B$. Do we have any rules or shortcuts to find them or do we have to do a trial and error method till we get the answer. I hope that's not the right way.

Please shed some light towards this!

Comment: If you just want to find **some** matrices $A,B$ such that $AB=I$, you can take $A=B=I$. I don't really understand what you are asking, can you clarify?

Comment: Given an invertible matrix, there is a step by step process to find its inverse.

Comment: We need to find the matrices AB = I such that neither A or B is I(Identity matrix). So we need to find two non Identity matrices and when we multiply that the result should be I.

Comment: Any matrix which represents an elementary row operation on another matrix could work, they are invertible and their inverses easy to find. Plus you can make them as large or as small as you want

Answer (score 2):

The standard "beginner's" method for matrix inversion is [Gauss-Jordan elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination#Finding_the_inverse_of_a_matrix).

Here are some $4 \times 4$ examples that work out reasonably simply.

$$A = \left[ \begin {array}{cccc} 2&-2&-1&-3\cr 2&-3&0&-3
\cr -1&-1&2&0\cr -1&3&-2&-2
\end {array} \right],\ B = A^{-1} =  
 \left[ \begin {array}{cccc} -12&11&-9/2&3/2\cr -10&9
&-7/2&3/2\cr -11&10&-7/2&3/2\cr 2&-2
&1/2&-1/2\end {array} \right]$$

$$A = \left[ \begin {array}{cccc} -1&0&1&0\\ 2&0&1&1
\\ -1&1&3&-1\\ 1&0&3&1\end {array}
 \right],\ B = A^{-1} = 
 \left[ \begin {array}{cccc} -2&-1&0&1\\ 6&6&1&-5
\\ -1&-1&0&1\\ 5&4&0&-3
\end {array} \right] 
$$

Answer (score 0):

You could take a matrix of the form
$$
M =\pmatrix{A_1&0\\0&A_2}
$$
where $A_1$ and $A_2$ are invertible $2 \times 2$ matrices. This reduces the dimension of the problem from $4$ to $2$. Then, you can also take the matrices $P^{-1}MP$ where $P$ is one of the matrices proposed by Robert Israel...